# Rails how to update image? And how to do RESTful routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to update my photographer model. But how problems with Rails routing and paperclip wont replace image.

When I submit my form the url is: `http://localhost:3000/admin/photographers/save.75` which gives an error. `Couldn't find Photographer without an ID`

And my image is not updated.

My form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @photographer, :url => save_admin_photographers_path(@photographer), :html => {:multipart => true, :method => :post} do |f| %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "tiny_mce/tiny_mce" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "init_my_tiny_mce" %>

  <%= f.input :name, :label => 'Name' %>
  <%= f.text_area :text, :label => 'Text', :size => '12x12' %>
  <%= f.file_field :image, :label => 'Image' %>
  <% if @photographer %>
    <% if @photographer.image %>
      <p class="ok">
        <label for="dd">image ok</label>
        <%= image_tag("http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/kjacobsen/photographer/image/#{@photographer.id}/#{@photographer["image"]}", :size => "39x22") %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="sdd">&nbsp;</label>
        <%= link_to("remove", {:action => "remove_image", :id => @photographer.id}, {:confirm => "Are your sure?"}) %>
      </p>
    <% else %>
      <p class="current">
        <label for="dd"></label>
        No image uploaded for movie
      </p>
    <% end %>
    <br />
  <% end %>

  <br />
  <%= f.file_field :flv, :label => 'Upload FLV' %>
  <br />
  <% if @photographer %>
    <% if @photographer.flv %>
      <p class="ok">
        <label for="dd">flv: <%= @photographer["flv"] %></label>
        <%= link_to("remove", {:action => "remove_flv", :id => @photographer.id}, {:confirm => "Are your sure?"}) %>
      </p>
    <% else %>
      <p class="current">
        No flv uploaded
        <br /><br />
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <br />
  <%= f.file_field :quicktime, :label => 'Upload Quicktime' %>
  <br />
  <% if @photographer %>
    <% if @photographer.quicktime %>
      <p class="ok">
        <label for="dd">quicktime:  <%= @photographer["quicktime"] %></label>
        <%= link_to("remove", {:action => "remove_quicktime", :id => @photographer.id}, {:confirm => "Are your sure?"}) %>
      </p>
    <% else %>
      <p class="current">
        <label for="dd"></label>
        No quicktime uploaded
        <br />
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>


  <%= f.button :submit, :value => 'Create movie' %>
<% end %>
```

My update controller:

```
def save            
  @photographer = Photographer.find(params[:id])            
  @photographer.update_attributes(params[:photographer])    

  if !@photographer.save                                
    flash[:notice] = "&nbsp;"
    render_action 'edit'            
  else
    flash[:notice] = "update ok"
    redirect_to :action => 'edit', :id => @photographer.id          
  end       
end
```

My routes:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :photographers do
    collection do
      post :save
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is basically an `update` action. The update route is automatically created when you do `resources :photographers`, you can verify this by typing `rake routes` in the terminal.

You should rename your controller action from `save` to `update`  and remove the custom route:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :photographers
end
```

Then use the `update` route in your form:

```
:url => admin_photographer_path(@photographer)
```

You should also change your html method, the update action uses `PUT`:

```
:method => :put
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried but get the following when submitting the form: No route matches "/admin/photographers/75"

Comment: @Railsbeginner what does `rake routes` says? I also assume your controller name is `Admin::PhotographersController`?

Comment: Yes my controller does have that name